# Spinner is not stopping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, font-awesome

I am enabling a spinner as soon as the user submits the form. In the save after getting the response from the rest call i am hiding the spinner and changing the button to ok or close. Or incase if failure scenario user will get the error message on the page and button will be shows as Add.  In the below code the spinner is starting correctly, but after the servie call remaining statements executing properly but the spinner is hiding only after few seconds. If i enable the developer tools spinner is hiding after all exeuction completes.  Any inputs?
In the below screen shot user should not see the spinner once the button is enabled with Add text.  But it is still spinner for few seconds

Javascript code:

```
$scope.saveSDG = function () {
    $scope.save = true; //show spinner
    $scope.isDisabled = true;
    $scope.action="Applying"; 
    var inputJson = '{ "input" : ['+json+']}'; // assume json is the valid variable
    // videoProvisionSvc is another service  where i am calling REST api. after restcall below method will be executed
    videoProvisionSvc.provisionSDG(inputJson, function(data) { 
             $scope.save = false; //hide spinner
             var responsJson = JSON.parse(data);
             $scope.action ="close";
             $scope.$apply();
    }); 
};
```

Html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Other form fields-->
<button ng-click="saveSDG()" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="isDisabled" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin ng-hide" ng-show="save"></i> {{action}}
     </button>
</body>   
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Check [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/IQsfdIsezTEJsf6PX4Vi?p=preview) I've created to help differentiate what you have with a working example.

Comment: I have updated the plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/1noW0yJxEQgLgBrhS7UZ?p=preview) .   in my usecase I don't have time out.. i am changing the spinner flag to false/true after getting the response from the RESTcall.  But the spinner is getting stopped after few seconds.

Comment: Your plunk is working exactly as intended, no problems with it. I can't foresee your use case as being the issue. Maybe the service you're using is actually lagging that long?

Comment: right, even I don't understand.  The spinner should be disappeared as soon as the flag set to false.  But it is still showing for few seconds which will be bad user experience.

Comment: Is there any way you can reproduce this so that others can see? The Plunker you linked above is working fine. Perhaps with the service (or a mock version) that encounters the issue?

Comment: i have tried replicating the same in this splunker but the spinner is not getting stopped at all.  http://plnkr.co/edit/1noW0yJxEQgLgBrhS7UZ